# Send specific message to specific socket.id with socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm having problem finding the right answer for my problem. I want to had private messaging for every user like Telegram if I may say. Or like notifications on StackOverflow the socket event are only send to specific user.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // this will be only sent to a user that just connected
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

But how to send specific message with custom id?

Here my **socket.js**

```
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const { redis, saveUser } = require('./redis')

module.exports.listen = function(app){
io = socketio.listen(app)

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connected user', socket.id)

  socket.on('join', (payload) => {
    redis.get(payload.email (err, socket_id) => {
      socket.broadcast.to(socket_id).emit('join', `Hello ${payload.whoChat.name} Chat you`)
      })
    })      
  })

return io
}
```

but this doesn't send anything to my user, if using rooms it will send directly to the rooms and when i look for docs `io.to()` and `io.broadcast.to()` can be use with sockets rooms.

so i decided to take it simple but wrong here my **server.js** rigth now.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('join', payload => {
   socket.emit('join', payload)
})
```

and on client-side

```
socket.on('join', (payload) => { 
    // Compare data from socket with local data if match then push the message 
    // to users who recieve
    if ( payload.userId === localData.userId ) {
        this.message.push(payload.message)
    }
})
```

but with that actually I send it to all users... how to do it properly and right? and how to save the users socket.id? since socket.id are generated randomly how do you save it for the future request when user disconnect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to maintain a *map* of _socket_id/user_id_

## Server

```js
const sessionsMap = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('askForUserId');

  socket.on('userIdReceived', (userId) => {
    sessionsMap[userId] = socket.id;
  });

  socket.on('send', (message) => {
    const receiverId = sessionsMap[message.receiverId];
    const messageData = message.data;
    socket.broadcast.to(receiverId).emit('my message', messageData);
  });
});
```

## Client

```js
const userId = 'FOO';

io.on('askForUserId', () => {
  io.emit(userId);
});

io.on('send', (message) => {
  console.log('You received a message');
  console.log(message.data);
});
```

## Note

Make sure to check out the [Socket.IO cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) it covers a lot of commands and use cases.

Comment: so the sessions map I get from the database? or sessions maybe. something that should be saved forever when user connect? Is there the need to use rooms and namespaces?  edit to you answer,  `sessionsMap[userId] = sessionId ;` or where do the `socketId` comes from?

Comment: edited the answer. `socketId` is actually `socket.id` (typo). You don't _need_ to store the `sessions map` in a database. As you can see I used a basic javascript object `const sessionsMap = {};`. Although you _can_ store that in database too, if you're going down that road, consider using [Redis](https://redis.io/) as it is faster (in memory database)

Comment: what the use of `sessionId` variable there?

Comment: yeah you don't need that variable too, I mixed `socketId` with `socket.id` and `sessionId`. They are all the same, I edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: Do i still need, rooms and namespace?

Comment: This should do the trick but have you tested the solution? With that being said, it depends on your use case, check out the docs to see what module you may want to use.

Comment: yeah the solution works like charm thanks. ill do more researh on.rooms and namespace maybe that could help.

Comment: This is a good start, but we need to take into consideration edge cases like a single user connected through multiple clients (keeping an updated mapping between users and connected sockets) , and multi node socket.io implementations