# I want to send a message to a particular client with socket.io in swift (IOS)?

Tags: node.js, swift, sockets, emit

My code in `nodejs` is OK and works fine. I can send a message from server to a particular client (i use email for send message) with below code:

```
io.sockets.in('julia.girldeveloper@example.com').emit('messages', 'Hello i am julia');
```

But in Swift I don't know how to send message to a particular client.

Can anyone help me to write the above code in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure it on server and on client.

Here [my question from long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076404/send-specific-message-to-specific-socket-id-with-socket-io) ago but I'll explain it here too.

Each of your user connected you should gave it ID. Store it on database or whatever map could be use to. Remember ID must be unique like `emails`, `userid` or whatever unique.

## Server.js

```
const sessionsMap = {}; // I save user ID here

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('askForUserId');

  socket.on('userIdReceived', (userId) => {
    sessionsMap[userId] = socket.id; // save the users on database or Object up to you
  });

  socket.on('send', (message) => {
    const receiverId = sessionsMap[message.receiverId];
    const messageData = message.data;
    socket.broadcast.to(receiverId).emit('mymessage', messageData);
  });
});
```

## Client

Sorry I don't know swift but its same (I hope you get the point), servers handle the message send to who and came to who.

```
const userId = 'julia@mail.me'; // this should be unique

io.on('askForUserId', () => {
  io.emit(userId); // your connected user ID save it.
});

io.on('mymessage', (message) => {
  console.log('Yoho had message from', message.senderId)
  console.log(message.text)
});

// send message to other people
io.emit('send', { text: 'Hellow', receiverId: 'john@doe.net', senderId: 'julia@mail.me' })
```

Comment: I mean the Implementation is same, whether you use swift or not. look at the last line and how the server handles it. Its not swift its the server who handles the message came to who. swift only say the direction.  https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift look at those example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for the Swift language.

```
import SocketIO
import Foundation

let serverURL = "YourServerURL"

class SocketOpration {

    static let shared = SocketOpration(socketURL: URL(string: serverURL)!)

    let socketURL: URL
    var socket:SocketIOClient!
    var manager:SocketManager!


   init(socketURL: URL) {
        self.socketURL = socketURL
        self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: self.socketURL, config: [.log(false)])
        self.socket = self.manager.defaultSocket
   }

    func setup() {

          socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {[weak self] data, ack in
              print("socket connected")
          }

          socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) {[weak self] data, ack in
            print("socket disconnected")
          }


        // Get emit Call via On method ( emit will fire from Node )

         socket.on("messages") { [weak self](data, ack) in
            if data.count > 0 {
            }
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you help me in socket connection